# RESTful status code for a request that cannot be satisfied because of a dependency issue

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

My `payment` endpoint which accepts a `POST` should deny requests when the user does not have any `payment methods` configured. What is the correct HTTP status code in this case?

What is the correct HTTP status code to be raised when the system itself cannot reach the state asked for by the request and another request (creating a payment method) must be completed first?

I looked at `428 Precondition Required`, but that seems to have more to do with the headers than the state of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go simply with `400 Bad Request`. If you need more specific instructions or hints in the response, you can return a body, which will indicate the exact nature of the error.

You don't need to assign a specific HTTP error code to all your internal business-related error cases. Indeed this is probably not possible anyway.

The specification on 400: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1

Relevant quotes from there:

> indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error

And about the `4xx` codes in general:

> the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition

Comment: My problem with 400 is that the RFC makes it sound like this is due to the request being malformed rather than the state of the system being wrong. For example there is no indication that the same request should be retried and will succeed once a payment method is created for that account.

Comment: See my edit with 2 relevant quotes for your case. Summary: `400` is ok for this case (my interpretation of course), and the returned body should contain the information you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into error 424 Failed_Dependency? I think this could bethe one you want.

See
http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/424_-_Failed_Dependency

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `422 Unprocessable Content`.

Same time it looks almsot the same as `400 Bad Request`.